# FFMPEG - 1080i - Using yadif and images still seem blurred/interlaced

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-filters

I am trying to look at getting some images automatically from an mp4 that was recorded from a 1080i output. We usually receive 1080p and all works well. But in this instance, that is not an option. We use the following FFMPEG command in normal circumstances and it works well. However, with 1080i we are getting the interlacing/blur.

> ffmpeg -i "Video.mp4" -qscale:v 2 -vf yadif=1:0:0 -r 1 "%06d.jpg"

Does anyone know of an improved command that can work with 1080i to make the movement crisp?

Many Thanks.

[image: example image]

Comment: Are you certain about your source ? Maybe yadif=0,-1,0 or yadif=1,-1,0 will yield correct results ? Alternatively, look into using a different deinterlacing filter (bwdif, estdif, ...).

Comment: I am certain the source is 1080i and this is the only time we have the issue. The same source on 1080p is fine. I'll try bwdif and estdif and report back

Comment: Just test all 4 variants the images are the same.

Comment: Maybe something else happened here as well like NTSC/PAL conversion. I suggest you upload like a 10s clip from the source material so others can try to extract a better image from it and share the settings.

Comment: We are still struggling with this but I have come up with a temporary fix. We are playing the video and screen capturing again as 1080p. There is a slight quality drop but at least the frames are crisp.